# Salesforce platform license and Box integration - what is supported?

Tags: integration

We are trying to find out whether the limited Salesforce platform license supports use of Box integration and if so, how it can be set up using permission sets.

Answer (score 2):

The platform licence does support the use of Box, and you just enable the Box permission set for the users you want to allow using it. The process is pretty straightforward, check the Box resources for further instructions.